# getActionBar() returning null in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am trying to build Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

**My `FragmentActivity` is :**

```
public class BookDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Description", "Find book"};
    static ArrayList<String> book;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_books_details);

        book = new ArrayList<String>();
        book = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bookMap");

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), book, getApplicationContext());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getRequiredData() {
        return book;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

But i am getting an error in:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

**The error says:**

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: use getSupportActionBar() instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActionBar() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203624/android-studio-actionbar-tablistener-does-not-work-with-appcompatactivity it is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pooya. `getSupportActionBar()` should work

Answer (score 1):

change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`

also change FragmentActivity to AppcompatActivity

Answer (score 1):

**[Android Studio: ActionBar.TabListener does not work with AppCompatActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203624/android-studio-actionbar-tablistener-does-not-work-with-appcompatactivity)**

`ActionBar.TabListener` is a deprecated `interface`.I hope you will not use that in future.

**And, `ActionBarTabs` can be replaced by:**

> - `TabLayout` from the `Android Design Support Library`, with or without a
>     [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html); or
> - a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and your favorite other tab solution for it, whether that
>     be `PagerTabStrip` or [*any number of third-party tab implementations*](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111); or
> - [`FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Like i said before in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35203962/4409113

But for fixing the issue, **That's because `ActionBar`** was not enabled for the right theme and you are extending `FragmentActivity`.

Please check this link: [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520344/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-setdisplayhomeasupe)

Use `AppCompatActivity` instead to add `ActionBar` and if you used it, you will need this too:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```